# Difference filter in query

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2016

I have a table invoicessales. I need to exclude all lines where having  `round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 and round(sum(Amount),1) =0`

I try two queries with different filter:

Query1 : returns 12745 rows

```
select sum(    QtyInvoiced ) , sum(Amount) ,salesNumber 
    from invoicesales
   group by salesNumber 
having round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) <> 0 and round(sum(Amount),1)<>0
```

Query 2:  : returns 13265 rows more line than the Query1

```
 select sum(    QtyInvoiced ) , sum(Amount) ,salesNumber 
        from invoicesales
       group by salesNumber 
    HAVING NOT(ROUND( SUM(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 AND ROUND(SUM(Amount),1) = 0);
```

I didn't understand what it's the difference between the two filters?

Comment: can you check with `EXCEPT` operator between second and first query, you will see the rows you are not expecting to see

Comment: @Ven I try it. the first query return lines where  round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) <> 0 or round(sum(Amount),1)<>0

Comment: The second query will result for rows where it meets both `QtyInvoiced` and `Amount`

Comment: @ven what's the right query? It's the second one? Right?

Comment: Which values do you expect to see

Comment: Second query have rows with data, having 0 values either in `qty` or `amount`, suggest use second one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `second` query could have results , in meeting `either of conditions`, `first` query will have results only with meeting `both conditions`.

if you want to see quantity invoiced value aswel when it is positive, i guess your `sum(quantity)` is net of sales and returns. so if you also want to see quantity where net value is 0 use second query

if you like to see only rows meeting both  conditions, use first query.
here is sample

```
declare @table table (Salesnumber Int, QtyInvoiced  int,Amount money )
insert @table
select 1 ,2,20 union all
select 1 ,1,-10 union all
select 1 ,1,0 union all
select 2 ,2,20 union all
select 2 ,2,20 union all
select 2 ,2,20 union all
select 3 ,2,20 union all
select 3 ,1,-10 union all
select 4 ,1,0 union all
select 5 ,2,-20 union all
select 5 ,2,-20 union all
select 5 ,2,20 
--select * from @table
select sum(    QtyInvoiced ) Quantity , sum(Amount) Amount ,salesNumber 
    from @table
   group by salesNumber 
having round( sum(QtyInvoiced),1) <> 0 and round(sum(Amount),1)<>0

 select sum(    QtyInvoiced )Quantity  , sum(Amount) Amount ,salesNumber 
        from @table
       group by salesNumber 
    HAVING NOT(ROUND( SUM(QtyInvoiced),1) = 0 AND ROUND(SUM(Amount),1) = 0);
```

Comment: nice one! @Ven. Query1 count  + all sum(amount) = 0 = Query2 count. voting for this